# I added a character encoding (utf-8) response header and now my .css aren't being linked in

Tags: html, css

Situation: I have a rather large website (windows server 2003) I want to standardize to use only UTF-8. Right now it uses all kinds of character encodings and after squares started to appear on a particular page we decided there would be only one character encoding to be used (utf-8), including for the database it uses. This is to make the website easy to maintain. After changing everything to utf-8 it is not a problem if new squares show up that then need to be fixed in any way (without changing character encoding ofcourse).

I added a http response header which sets the character encoding to utf-8. In the website options in my browser I do see utf-8 appear now.

The problem is that .css files seem to no longer be having an effect (using the  tag, I can specify .css on the spot and it does work). When I remove these lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

The .css files are having an effect, but still the font does not look the same as before I changed the response headers. I also do not want to remove those lines.

How is it possible that setting to utf-8 stops my .css files from being linked used? I tried changing the options of my editors for the BOM and for character encoding, but I cannot solve the issue. What am I doing wrong? Maybe I shouldn't add that response header and standardize the website in an entirely different way alltogether?

Edit: Newly found out: if I add a character before the

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN
```

line it does work! I'd really like to know whats going on here.

Comment: Those lines have no business being in a CSS file. They are the opening information for HTML files. I don't think your problem is encoding related - the CSS file should work without UTF-8 support (as it's unlikely to contain non-ASCII characters). I would debug what exactly happens with the font.

Comment: Oh sorry I wasn't clear. Those lines are in the file that wants to load the .css file

Comment: Ah, okay. Strange. What do Firebug / Chrome's Developer Console say about the loading process of the CSS file?

Comment: The .css file is loaded, firebug says some text that I select has no style rules

Comment: The website is for internal use only, if thats what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some non UTF-8 character is breaking your HTML. You could have a quote in there that's breaking a delimiter because it's a MS-WORD (Windows 1251) quote instead of `"`. Without seeing your actual HTML, we can only guess.

Use a debugger, such as Firebug to inspect your HTML and it will show you where the syling comes from for that element. You may also want to run it through a validator to see if it's actually broken.

Comment: "It's possible that some non UTF-8 character is breaking your HTML" If I switch my editor(eclipse) to save as utf-8, does that mean this isn't possible?

Comment: If a character is encoded as Windows 1251, saving it as UTF-8 will not automatically convert those characters to the correct UTF-8 ones.

Comment: if I use php's "require_once" where it inserts the .css file right into the spot, it does work, so I think its not a broken character (unless the broken character is in the link-tag itself)

Comment: Sorry, its even crazier; If I add a "echo "bla";" in the php code before the header starts that refers to the .css file, the .css layout is used